# Get-vm where {_.created. Only list the first occurence of snapshot older than xxx

Tags: powershell, where-clause, snapshot

I want to check for vm snapshots that are older than a certain amount of days. The first script list all the vm's that meet that criteria.

```
$Snapshots = Get-Vm | Get-Snapshot | Where {$_.Created -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-3)} | Select-Object VM, Name, Created
```

Where as this script only shows the first occurrence of vm's that meet the criteria.

```
$Snapshots = Get-Vm | Get-snapshot where {$_.Created -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-3)} | Select-Object VM, Name, Created

if ($Snapshots.count -gt 0) {
    Write-Host "Found snapshots older than X!", $vm.name -ForegroundColor Yellow

}
else {
    Write-Host "Found no snapshots older than X!" -ForegroundColor Green
}
```

The reason I want to do it as shown in the second example is because i need to send different status codes to Icinga.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we assume `$Snapshots` contains the data you need, it will be a collection. You can selectively pick an element from that collection using an index `[0]` and display its properties (`$Snapshots[0].VM.Name`).

```
$Snapshots = Get-Vm | Get-Snapshot |
    Where Created -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-3) |
        Select-Object VM, Name, Created

if ($Snapshots.Count -gt 0) {
    Write-Host "Found snapshots older than X!", $Snapshots[0].VM.Name -ForegroundColor Yellow

}
else {
    Write-Host "Found no snapshots older than X!" -ForegroundColor Green
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You use wrong variable

```
$vm.name
```

Use instead:

```
$Snapshots.vm.Name
$Snapshots.Name
```

Or for all rows

```
Write-Host "Found snapshots older than X!", $Snapshots -ForegroundColor Yellow
```

Comment: `$Snapshots=Get-VM | Get-Snapshot | Select-Object VM, Name, Created|where {$_.Created -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-3)}`

And then you can access to actual VM name `$Snapshots.VM`